# Resize an image in a button C# (not background image)

Tags: c#, image, button, controls, imagebutton

I inserted an image into a button, but it's not a background image. So, I want to resize the image's size that I want for example `Height=30, Width=20` or sometime `Height=50, Width=50`. Some people told me that it's impossible to resize an image in a button if I inserted it as an background image it's possible.However, if I insist to resize the image it's possible? I don't believe that nobody can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a windows form application? Forgive me if I didn't understand the question, but you should be able to resize the image from the Properties menu if you're using a PictureBox. Right-click on the image you inserted, select properties and there should be a field for Size.

Comment: Yes!! it's a window form. How can i resize it if i had imported in a button ? If I use the property menu, it's belong to the button.

Comment: How exactly did you import it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to resize the image present inside the button. You can try something like this in Designer File:

```
// 
// ButtonName
// 
this.ButtonName.AutoSize = false;

Image image = new Bitmap(customWidth,customHeight);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image ))  {
g.DrawImage(FileLocation, 0, 0, customWidth, customHeight);
}

this.ButtonName.Image = image;
```

This will help in button resizing but the picture won't be clear if much increased.

Answer (score -2):

```
Button.Resize += Button_Resize;

private void Button_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Button button = (Button)sender;
Image resize = new Bitmap(button.Image,new Size(button.Image.Width, (button.Height - 13))); button.Image = resize;
}
```